# Jquery .load function seems to load page as a standalone page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Good day all,

I've been looking for a solution for ages but still haven't found any.

I'm building a platform and I'm using jQuery to refresh a div in one of my pages.
I know the refresh is working because when I `.load()` a simple page it's working.

The jQuery code I'm using is:

```
$('.refreshDIV').load('/pages/extra/results.php');
```

I also tried:

```
$('.refreshDIV').load('/pages/extra/results.php' + location.search);
```

The first line in `results.php` is:

```
<?php
if (!defined('INDEX')) {
    require('../../includes/config.php');
    header('Location: /');
    exit;
}
```

When I click the button to refresh the `.refreshDIV` it redirects me back to `/`, which assumes that `INDEX` is not defined and that the loaded page is being loaded as a "standalone" page.

When I comment out the first line I see an `error 500` in the console which seems to assume that the PHP code on that page is not working (it is depending on other pages).

The page with the div that needs to be refreshed looks like this:

```
<div class="refreshDIV">
<?php include('pages/extra/results.php'); ?>
</div>
```

The page itself is working fine, but like I said when I click the button to refresh the div I get redirected back to `/`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please, when you downvote add a comment to tell users what's wrong with their question so they can improve it... :)

Comment: It looks like that's what the code will do: If `INDEX` is not defined, it will redirect to `header('Location: /');`. How does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: @CKolkman You need to set the constant `INDEX` or remove the `!defined(...)` check

Comment: @showdev Yes that's correct but `INDEX` is defined so I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Where does `INDEX` get defined?

Comment: @Marcus Yes but `INDEX` is defined in `index.php` which is the "base" page for every page on the platform.

Comment: @showdev In `index.php` which is the "base" page for every page on the platform.

Comment: Is `INDEX` defined for `results.php`?

Comment: If you directly call results.php, index.php will not be executed and the constant will not be set.

Comment: @Marcus When I remove the `!defined(...)` check I get an `error 500` because the rest of the code in `results.php` is not working which assumes that `results.php` is not getting the PHP variables from other pages when being loaded with `.load()`, while it is working fine with the `include(...)`.

Comment: @CKolkman please post the code in your `index.php` and `results.php`

Comment: @Marcus Okay I understand, but how can I `.load()` a PHP page which depends on variables defined on other pages?

Comment: _“When I comment out the first line I see an error 500 in the console”_ - probably because you neglected to comment out the _last_ line as well …?

Comment: @misorude No the first line is enough, the `error 500` is because the rest of the PHP is not working like I said.

Comment: You _made_ it “not working”, by introducing a syntax error, _because_ you only commented the first line! The `}` on the last line is the _counterpart_ to the one at the end of `if (!defined('INDEX')) {` – so if you comment out that line, then the last one of course has to be commented out as well.

Comment: This is not an issue that has anything in particular to do with AJAX / `.load` to begin with. If you called `/pages/extra/results.php` directly via your browser address bar, no AJAX at all, you would of course have the exact same problem. _“In index.php which is the "base" page for every page on the platform.”_ - how exactly is it “the base” then? Where do you imagine the index.php would get involved, if you call `/pages/extra/results.php` _directly_? That does not include/require the index.php.

Comment: @misorude No that whole part including the end `}` is being commented out, like I said I commented out enough to make it work (in the `results.php` file it's one line code)

Comment: @misorude As example, the page is `mydomain.com/index.php?page=test`. The page `test.php` has the code ```<div class="refreshDIV">
<?php include('pages/extra/results.php'); ?>
</div>``` and a button to refresh `refreshDIV` with the same page that's included already `pages/extra/results.php`

Comment: In that case you have the index.php embedding the other script - so the other script has access to all the variables & constants defined by the index.php. When you request `/pages/extra/results.php` directly however, the index.php is not involved _at all_.

Comment: @misorude Okay I understand but I don't want to define the variables etc again on that page. I have it depend on `INDEX` so it cannot be accessed directly in the browser, eg `mydomain.com/pages/extra/results.php` so it has also access to all the variables.

Comment: _“I have it depend on INDEX so it cannot be accessed directly in the browser”_ - but with `$('.refreshDIV').load('/pages/extra/results.php');` you _are_ requesting it “directly” - to your server, there is little difference between calling this via the address bar, or via an AJAX request. (jQuery sends an `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header with AJAX requests, so you _could_ use that to differentiate between both types of requests.)

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it seems that you did not set the constant `INDEX`, which is set in the `index.php`.
The condition `!defined('INDEX')` will always return `true`.

As a result the code `header('Location: /');` will be executed, which will redirect you to the new page instead of loading the content.

You need to either define the constant in the `results.php` or remove the check `!defined('INDEX')`.

Comment: I can imagine that's correct but everything is already defined/set in the page that's already loaded.

Comment: @CKolkman You are calling the results.php file, it "does not know" what information the previously loaded index.php file has.

Comment: This would mean I have to define all the variables or include the correct pages again in `results.php`